# TgBot doesn't find owner ban power

Tags: c++, telegram-bot

I've started programming my own telegram-bot in cpp with tgbot-cpp and I've done the code for the ban. When the code checks if the user has the power to ban, it finds the needed power for admins, but not for the owner of the group. I looked in the documentation if there was a way to find the owner of the group, but I couldn't find it. This is the code section that checks the power.

```
    /* Checks if the client has the permission to ban */
    bool hasPermission = false;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < admins.size(); i++) {
        if (admins[i]->user->id == message->from->id) {
            printf("Admin username: %s\n", admins[i]->user->username.c_str());
            printf("Can Restrict: %d\n", admins[i]->canRestrictMembers);

            if (admins[i]->canRestrictMembers) {
                hasPermission = true;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasPermission) {
        return;
    }
```

When an admin uses the ban command, I get a `Can Restrict: 1` in the console, but when the owner uses the command I get a `Can Restrict: 0`.
Is there a reason why the bot doesn't see the owner's power? Is there a way to look for the owner?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited to the project's mailing list or author email account?

Comment: I'm not sure it's an issue of the bot. It could be that I didn't see something in the documentation, but I'll try that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking better in the documentations, there is a value `status` for `ChatMember` that is setted to `creator` for the owner of the group. That seems to be the way for checking if someone is the owner or not, avoiding the permission issue